# Gaussian Mixture Models EM algorithm use average log likelihood to test convergence

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian

I was investigating scikit-learn's implementation of the EM algorithm for fitting Gaussian Mixture Models and I was wondering how they did come up with using the [average log likelihood](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/mixture/gmm.py#L515) instead of the sum of the log likelihoods to test convergence.

I see that it should cause the algorithm to converge faster (given their default parameters), but where does that idea come from ?

Does anyone know if they based this part of the implementation on a specific paper or if they just came up with it and used it ?

In most explanations of the EM algorithm I have come across, they would have used log_likelihoods.sum() instead of log_likelihoods.mean().

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes unit testing easier; invariant to the size of the sample.

Reference: [the github discussion that led to the change](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4178).

Comment: @Dawny33 no hard feeling, but I still don't understand why you rejected the edit. I just believe that  what I'm saying states the same thing as Emre but with clearer. :)

Comment: @Emre what do you think ? I think your answer is great but it just need some clarifications.

Comment: @eliasah many of your edits are putting lots of words in the answerer's mouth. They may or may not be right; they shouldn't be an edit. Write your own answer, or comment.